# Get all months and years between two datetime

Tags: c#

What I need is to get logic on how to get monthname-year between two dates.

```
Dictionary<Monthname,year> GetMonthsandYear(Datetime d1,Datetime d2) 
       or
List<Tuple<string,int> GetMonthsandYear(Datetime d1,Datetime d2)
```

example : jan-1-2013  to mar-3-2013

should return January-2013,february-2013,march-2013 or in reverse format by list.reverse

Comment: What have you tried so far? And would the result be any different if you started with (say) January 20th 2013 and March 10th 2013? (Would that only include January and February?)

Comment: Thanks Jon for replying.I am trying to figure it so thought of asking.Requirement is to get (monthname,year) starting from current date to last 2 years date and to show in dropdowm.                        So if I get Dictionary<Monthname,Year> would work.

Comment: Well that hasn't answered my questions about the requirements - and I *really* don't think you want a dictionary, as the order of dictionaries is unspecified.

Comment: Sorry to clarify I need months-year pair, advised by one peer to write a IEnumerable<Tuple<string,int>> which will yield the result.To answer to your question yes it has to include march also.Result expected Feb-2014,Jan-2014,Dec-2013,Nov-2013............to Feb-2012.Thanks.

Comment: Just because you need a month-year pair at some point doesn't mean that's what your method needs to return. It's often better to return a "purer" form of data and transform it for presentation later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your actual requirement is "the previous 24 months" then it's much simpler. Just start off with the current month, and get the 1st day of it - then iterate and add 1 month 24 times.

Personally I'd return an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` rather than anything else - you can format each element however you want - but it's pretty simple:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMonths(int count)
{
    // Note: this uses the system local time zone. Are you sure that's what
    // you want?
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    // Always return the 1st of the month, so we don't need to worry about
    // what "March 30th - 1 month" means
    var startOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield return startOfMonth;
        startOfMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(-1);
    }
}
```

Then if you want a `List<string>` of these values as "February 2014" etc for example, you could have:

```
var monthYears = GetMonths(24).Select(dt => dt.ToString("MMMM yyyy"))
                              .ToList();
```

Note that a `Dictionary<...>` would *not* be appropriate unless you really don't care about the order - and I suspect you do. You shouldn't rely on the order in which items are returned from a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` when you view it as a sequence - it's not intended to be an ordered collection.

Comment: Thanks both to Jon and Soner for guiding me towards right direction.I got the idea to proceed.Sorry Soner only accept one answer.

Comment: @coder001 No problem `;)` Jon's answer has better qaulity (as always) than mine.

Comment: Just one small updatation on Jon's answer as per my requirement startOfMonth.AddMonths(-1) Thnx.

Comment: @coder001: Why? This code already returns the current month. Your requirements don't say that you wanted to start with the previous month.

Comment: Your code returned me Feb-2014,Mar-2014,Apr-2014 ..like that.But I expect this set starting from today back to previous 2 years.Hope I am able to explain.More precisely DateTime object1 (Today) DateTime object2 (Today-2 years).

Comment: @coder001: Ah, I see. It wasn't terribly clear from your comments.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand why you need `Dictionary` or `List<Tuple<string,int>` but one solution could be;

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2013, 3, 3);

while (dt1 < dt2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToString("MMMM-yyyy"));
    dt1 = dt1.AddMonths(1);
}
```

Result will be;

```
January-2013
February-2013
March-2013
```

Even if you need, you can add these values to a `List<string>` in `while` loop.

But be carefull about what Jon *[said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971268/get-all-months-and-years-between-two-datetime#comment33292414_21971268)*, this solution will generate only January and February if your `dt1.Day` is greater than `dt2.Day`.